# Plagiarism in a Patent Application

Tags: prior-art-request, copyright

This patent has, as part of its content about projective geometry, text and diagrams copied from my web site http://www.nct.anth.org.uk/ without permission or acknowledgement.  Is that ethical in a patent application?

Comment: Can you please specify which patent it is?

Comment: Plagiarizing is only an academic offense, it would be copyright violation that would potentially matter. A patent application containing copyright material without permission would not affect patentability unless it showed the inventor wasn't actually the inventor.

Comment: I suspect that fair use could be claimed for material copied into a patent application, because no rights are claimed in the work under copyright except for the clear exceptions in MPEP 608.

Comment: Related to: http://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/12449/has-anyone-used-copyright-infringement-in-the-application-as-grounds-to-block

Comment: Related: http://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/44/are-text-and-images-in-the-patent-copyrighted?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

It is common in patent applications to describe the "background art".  Proper attribution should be made.