# How to get Copyright permission for a figure in a patent

Tags: copyright, us20130256198

I would like to get permission for reusing Figure 26 of the United States Patent US20130256198, "Magnetic separation of electrochemical cell materials", in my review paper and thesis, with slight modifications. This paper is a part of my thesis. My review paper will be submitted to the Journal of Applied Electrochemistry soon. The title of my paper is “Recycling of Graphite Anodes for the Next Generation of Lithium Ion Batteries”. Dr. Gerardine G. Botte, professor at Ohio University, is the corresponding author of this journal article. Please advice me in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

You need not obtain permission to use the figure as per http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_on_the_content_of_patents_and_in_the_context_of_patent_prosecution#cite_note-2

Also, see answers to this previous question; [Are text and images in the patent copyrighted?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/44/are-text-and-images-in-the-patent-copyrighted)

You may visit the below link to know more about patent drawings:
http://www.invntree.com/blogs/patent-drawings-and-their-importance-in-a-patent-specification