# Printing the patent image from US patent

Tags: licensing, usa, copyright

IN reference to :- [US2249572](http://www.google.com/patents/US2249572) Wearable bone-conduction hearing aid

Do I need permission to print an image from patent?

Is it public domain?

USE:- Printing would be on vinyl wallcovering and installed in college building.

Comment: related: http://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/12449/has-anyone-used-copyright-infringement-in-the-application-as-grounds-to-block?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Unless it has a specific copyright notice, patent images are in the public domain.

See [Are text and images in the patent copyrighted?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/q/44/9802)

Comment: copyright could have been expired. i think become public after 60 years.