# What is the procedure to use the patent as a reference for our presentation in a conference?

Tags: law

In reference to the patent: [US20110209929](https://www.google.com/patents/US20110209929)

Comment: related: http://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/44/are-text-and-images-in-the-patent-copyrighted?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

Patents can be cited freely in educational activities.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has a page on this: [Copyright on the content of patents and in the context of patent prosecution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_on_the_content_of_patents_and_in_the_context_of_patent_prosecution#cite_note-2)

But depending on where you are in the world / US there may be restrictions on using the inventors name e.g. [California Right of Publicity Law](http://www.dmlp.org/legal-guide/california-right-publicity-law)

Comment: The cited link to the California Right of Publicity Law suggests that law wouldn't apply to the use of inventor's names at a conference since it isn't commercial purpose and advertising.